# Intellij 2018.1 is not able to load any directory or project

Tags: swing, intellij-idea, awt, intellij-plugin

I have installed intellij 2018.1 from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows

Getting the below error on opening a project/directory

[image]

My system configuration:

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Home Insider Preview Single Language
OS Version:                10.0.17672
BIOS Version:              Dell Inc. 1.5.4
```

Logs:

```
    E:\Apps\ideaIU-2018.1.4.win\bin>idea.bat
java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot load system cursor: CopyDrop.32x32
        at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.lazilyLoadDesktopProperty(WToolkit.java:894)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.getDesktopProperty(Toolkit.java:1808)
        at java.awt.dnd.DragSource.load(DragSource.java:131)
        at java.awt.dnd.DragSource.<clinit>(DragSource.java:148)
        at com.intellij.ide.palette.impl.PaletteWindow.<init>(PaletteWindow.java:90)
        at com.intellij.ide.palette.impl.PaletteToolWindowManager.<init>(PaletteToolWindowManager.java:43)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
        at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:103)
        at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:80)
        at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:63)
        at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:459)
        at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:106)
        at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:90)
        at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:77)
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectImpl.init(ProjectImpl.java:262)
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.initProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:274)
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.newProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:190)
        at com.intellij.platform.PlatformProjectOpenProcessor.doOpenProject(PlatformProjectOpenProcessor.java:217)
        at com.intellij.platform.PlatformProjectOpenProcessor.doOpenProject(PlatformProjectOpenProcessor.java:89)
        at com.intellij.ide.impl.ProjectUtil.openOrImport(ProjectUtil.java:131)
        at com.intellij.ide.actions.OpenFileAction.doOpenFile(OpenFileAction.java:81)
        at com.intellij.ide.actions.OpenFileAction.lambda$actionPerformed$0(OpenFileAction.java:56)
        at com.intellij.openapi.fileChooser.ex.FileChooserDialogImpl.choose(FileChooserDialogImpl.java:162)
        at com.intellij.openapi.fileChooser.FileChooser.chooseFiles(FileChooser.java:114)
        at com.intellij.openapi.fileChooser.FileChooser.chooseFiles(FileChooser.java:91)
        at com.intellij.ide.actions.OpenFileAction.actionPerformed(OpenFileAction.java:48)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.invokeAction(ActionUtil.java:337)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.invokeAction(ActionUtil.java:324)
        at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.ActionLink$1.linkSelected(ActionLink.java:60)
        at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel.doClick(LinkLabel.java:142)
        at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.ActionLink.doClick(ActionLink.java:69)
        at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel$MyMouseHandler.mouseReleased(LinkLabel.java:319)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6548)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6313)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4903)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4725)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4725)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:786)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:723)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:395)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.awt.AWTException: Exception: class java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 171 occurred while creating cursor CopyDrop.32x32
        at java.awt.Cursor.getSystemCustomCursor(Cursor.java:363)
        at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.lazilyLoadDesktopProperty(WToolkit.java:892)
        ... 69 more
```

**Tried to install/uninstall/re-install multiple times already but the same error.**
can anyone help me on this one please ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable this plugin by creating a text file named **disabled_plugins.txt** inside **config** directory, which is under

```
<SYSTEM DRIVE>\Users\<USER ACCOUNT NAME>\.<PRODUCT><VERSION>\config
```

with following content:

```
com.intellij.uiDesigner
```

Similar issue: [intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207295405/comments/203694684](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207295405/comments/203694684)
Config directory location: [intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519)

Comment: Sorry i failed to mention this, but I have already tried that method, after disabling the plugin the IDE boots up, but the project doesn't get loaded and nothing works :)